# Bootstrap Typeahead search issue with data contains HTML

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead

I am facing issue with bootstrap typeahead with data contains HTML angular brackets. My data is like

```
var jsonData = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "<Andrew> Pougher"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Michele Moore"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Michele Boob"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Michael Moore"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "George Michael"
  }
]
```

If I type "u" in input field, it will create  tag in HTML and values search dropdown displayes with value like "**Pougher**" instead of **< Andrew > Pougher**

Comment: Did you ever solve the problem; and what kind of typeahead are you using ...?

Comment: bootstrap typeahead I am using

Comment: Yes :) But which one? There is several different implementations and it vary between BS versions, you have tagged two different  ...